# Windows server how to install newest apache with php 5.6

Tags: apache-2.4, windows-server-2016, php5

I was requested by a client to setup a Windows server 2016 for using a 3rd party app.

The app requires to run on php 5.6. The security department of the company requires that the apache will be at least 2.4.39.

I tried to install xampp. I found an archive that supports [php 5.6.40](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/5.6.40/), but apache version is 2.4.38:

```
PS C:\xampp\apache\bin> .\httpd.exe -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.38 (Win64)
Apache Lounge VC11 Server built:   Jan 21 2019 13:25:29

PS C:\xampp\php> .\php.exe -v
PHP 5.6.40 (cli) (built: Jan  9 2019 15:10:36)
```

Is there a way to install on windows server a newer apache version with php 5.6?

Comment: PHP 5.6. has been unsupported since 1. of January 2019. If the security department requires up to date Apache, they should probably require up to date PHP as well..

Comment: I agree, but I don't make the shots. The application can only be run on php 5.6, so that's a hard limitation (I asked the developer and he said php 7 will probably break the app, and that there are "no urgent plans to upgrade". I would laugh if I wasn't crying hehe

Comment: I managed to install following instructions in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kuMTZowwjus

Comment: @justadev remind to answer your question on yourself in case its done, so we don't have many zombie Questions which means to be unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to install following instructions in this video: [youtube.com/watch?v=kuMTZowwjus](https://youtube.com/watch?v=kuMTZowwjus)

PHP from: https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/

Apache from: https://www.apachelounge.com/download/

Then a bunch of settings in the configurations that are explained in the video

Comment: and accept it ;)

Comment: I am required to wait 2 days. I will try to remember :)